# How do I get a Canon LBP 2900 printer working?

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

i am unable to set up my canon lbp2900 printer on ubuntu12.04 64 bit i aliened the 64 bit rpm drivers and then installed the drivers (version 2.40) and followed the procedure in the canon guide ( however i changed fifo path to //localhost:59787 (somebody suggested) instead of 59687 (as suggested by canon guide) )

intially i got the message pstocapt failed .. the drivers had put the pstocapt and backend/ccp in the lib64 directory instead of the lib directory ... i copied that to the aproprite directory under lib

but still i get the error "ccp send_data error exit " i also tried with fifo path //localhost:59687

i also tried the Radu script but the drivers the script uses are version 1.90 and has conflicting packages

Comment: I have followed the link which worked for me ...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/383695/installing-canon-lbp2900b-over-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 1):

### For 12.04

Don't worry, for printing you have to enter the following everytime after fresh boot:

```
sudo modprobe usblp
ls -l /dev/usb/lp0
sudo ccpd start
```

It works for me with the 32-bit driver installed according to the community documentation.

Comment: Please link the community docs, and cite the relevant sections. It is for the good of this site, and the Internet.

Comment: (1) You may want to explain how to make this run automatically on boot (with `/etc/rc.local`, or otherwise). (2) The `ls` command does not change anything--it just shows some information about the `lp0` device entry. So why should the `ls` command be run each time?