# How to install Canon LBP2900b drivers?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am trying very hard to install Canon LBP2900b Printer in Ubuntu 13.10. 
I have searched and googled a lot for the solution over fortnight but none of the site / link gave me the simple solution for me. How can accomplish my goal?